# SQL get date of upcoming Friday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff, dateadd

How do I get the date of upcoming/next Friday using SQL?

If the current day is Friday, then return today's date.

Thanks so much, any tips and advice appreciated!

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 14):

```
declare @date datetime
select @date = GETDATE()

SET DATEFIRST 6
SELECT DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(dw, @Date), @Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,(CASE DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 7 THEN 6 
                    ELSE 6 - DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()) END),GETDATE());
```

Comment: this returns tomorrow when i execute it today but it should be the day after tomorrow ;)

Comment: Really? For me it somehow returns `2014-05-23 13:27:49.760`, which happens to be day after tomorrow, a Friday

Comment: The result you get will depend on what `@@DATEFIRST` is.

Comment: @GarethD ah thx for the tip that explains it with value 7 it works.